# Reclaiming tablespace after dropping user in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-administration, tablespace

I am using oracle 10g. I have created two schema/user (let's assume produser for production and devuser for development) and allocate same table space let's say "prod" and both schemas/users have some data stored in same tablespace/datafile so here my problem  is first, if I drop one schema/user then related tablespace will automatically cleared or not?, if not then how can we reclaim of dropped schema/user tablespace without dropping tablespace/datafile? if you have any please suggest "How"? It will be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically cleared" in this context?  If you dropped a user, all that user's segments will be freed.  That means that they are free to be reused by any other object in the given tablespace when that object needs to add an extent.  It will have no impact on the size of any of the tablespace's data files.  It will decrease the amount of the tablespace's allocated size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For clarification when i check datafile size (let's say 10 GB assuming two user/schema) after dropping one user again checked and i found same size (even in os level) why it's size not freed or it's just water mark label for data to be refilled later when new object created, i think i am confusing here please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a tablespace as being synonymous with a disk partition on your PC. Lets say you bought a 500G disk and partitioned it into 300G for C: drive, and 200G for D: drive.

When you fill your C: drive with files and then delete those files, there is now  plenty of room C: drive for new files but *only* on C: drive. Deleting files on C: drive did not mean you get to use any of that free space for D: drive.

Tablespaces are the same.  Space you free up in a tablespace can be reused by other objects (new or otherwise) in that *same* tablespace.

If you want to give that space that you just freed up to a *different* tablespace (either an existing one or a new one) then this does not happen automatically. You *might* be able to do something like

```
alter database datafile '...' resize <some smaller value>
```

on the tablespace you just dropped objects from, which would mean it would free up space at the OS level, which would then be allocated to something else (database or otherwise). I say "might" because even if the tablespace is 99% empty, if the remaining objects are located at (say) the beginning AND end of the file, then you can't resize the file smaller than the logical high water mark of space utilised in the file.

Comment: Thank you sir for your logical answer it helps me somehow to understand tablespace. Thanks alot.